# hiding query parameters in the browser url in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to redirect to another url after successful login. Also when it redirects I also want to hide the query parameters.
This is my LoggedinGuard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (this.authService.getUser()) {
          return true;
        } 
        this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { redirectUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
```

after successful login the link in the browser is **http://localhost:4200/login?redirectUrl=%2Fgetup**

but I need to be displayed like **http://localhost:4200/login**

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your value using [state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) instead of a query param. (Just as you seem to already be doing with the `url` variable in the code shown)

```
this.router.navigate(['login'], { state: { redirectUrl: state.url }});
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. But its not working showing this error        Argument of type '{ state: { redirectUrl: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: angular 10. Is there any other solutuons available?

Answer (score 0):

In the component that is redirected to. Put this code snippet.

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common"; 

constructor(private location: Location) {}

ngOInit() {
 this.cleanURL();
}

cleanURL() {
// Use this method where its needed.
  this.location.replaceState('login');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is working in the first attempt. But when I reload the login page it doesn't get redirected to 'getup'